# javascript callback function after several jQuery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following code:

```
$('#some_object_id').hide();
$('div#some_version_div').hide();
$('#some_another_object_id').show();
someFunction();
```

I want to issue my `someFunction()` only after the last of these 3 finishes its action. The problem is that from time to time they finish in different order (ie now the last may be the second, the other time the first one etc.) Now `someFunction()` fires without waiting for these 3 to finish. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You're not passing a duration parameter to `show()` or `hide()`, so their effects should be immediate. So it seems to me the order should be reliable and the effects instantaneous.

Comment: @Utkanos - the default is actually 400ms (http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: In fact they are not instantaneous. They are made with some noticeable delays

Comment: It's default 400 only when passing params. If you pass none, it's null. From the docs: "[When called with no duration param,] the matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" )"

Comment: Because in your example you are actually setting the speed - to `null`!   -- The docs go on to say "When a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided, .hide() becomes an animation method. " meaning it will take on the default speed of 400ms of not set.

Comment: OK, here's the same result without passing null: https://jsfiddle.net/q7e9toxu/

Comment: However, I do concede that, even when effectively instantaneous, it's still asynchronous because, looking at the jQ source code, it still defers to its animation module, just with a duration of 0.

Comment: Good question for begineers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` functions accept a function as their argument which is called when they finish. (aka, a callback).

```
$('selector').hide(function onFinish() {
  console.log('done')
})
```

To combine three of them together, I'd convert them to a Promise, like so:

```
function promisify(func,selector){
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    $(selector)[func](resolve)
  })
}

Promise.all([
  promisify('hide', '#test'),
  promisify('hide', '#test1'),
  promisify('show', '#test2')
]).then(function onFinish() {
  console.log('done!')
})
```

Comment: How can I use Promise? Is it provided in javascript?

Comment: @artgb Yes, Promises are part of JavaScript. There's tons of great tutorials. Here's one: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: Well actually binding where you did is kind of pointless, here is a way without needing bind at all: https://jsfiddle.net/5o6btpnd/ just pass the function name, and selector and build the call in function.

Comment: @PatrickEvans At this point I feel like you should get credit for the answer. But thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function to hide, and show that gets executed when the animation is complete. So if you want them to execute in order just call each one in the callback of the previous one.

```
$('#some_object_id,div#some_version_div').hide(()=>{
  $('#some_another_object_id').show(()=>{
    someFunction();
  });  
});
```

And if you want to prevent a bunch of inner callbacks, and not require each animation run dependent of the others, you could use a flag. Increment the flag in each callback, check to see if its at a certain value, and then execute your function if it is.

```
var flag = 0;
function incrementFlag(){
   flag++;
   if(flag>=2){
     flag=0;
     someFunction();
   }
}
$('#some_object_id,div#some_version_div').hide(incrementFlag);
$('#some_another_object_id').show(incrementFlag);
```

You could also modify the above to use a Promise, but will leave that for you to try.

Comment: @artgb, how so?

Comment: If the code contains more hide and show you have to change further

Comment: Well the question wasn't about how to make a callback for an arbitrary number of calls.

Comment: Good question for beginners

Answer (score 0):

You should use a variable that you initially set to 0 and increase on every complete call. As soon as the variable hit the value 3 and can call your function:

```
var completed = 0;
elem.hide(400, function(){
    completed++;
    if(completed > 2) someFunction();
});
//same for other elements...
```